# does breaking expression into multiple variables slow execution

Tags: performance

I'm curious if I break an expression into different declarations e.g

```
int x = (c / 23) % (5 *3);
```

into

```
int a = c /23;
int b = 5 * 3;
int x = a % b;
```

does it slow down execution, or the compiler should recognize that it can be declared into one variable. (or some other trick)

I want to know if it can be a concern to give up some readability at a performance sensitive function.

Of course, I'm not asking about this particular example, my question is about the the general rule here.

I'm using C++, but I guess is that this question can be generalized to any - at least compiled - language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the optimization level selected for your compiler, separation into several lines of code should not matter.

You can always use the [Godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:23,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:23,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:23,selectionStartLineNumber:4,startColumn:23,startLineNumber:4),source:%27++++int+test(int+c)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++int+a+%3D+c+/23%3B%0A++++++++int+b+%3D+5+*+3%3B%0A++++++++int+x+%3D+a+%25+b%3B%0A++++++++return+x%3B%0A++++%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:vcpp_v19_24_x86,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Ox+/O2%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86+msvc+v19.24+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) to try and look at the resulting assembly code.